# kafka: Zookeeper mode - No Kafka brokers configured

Tags: apache-kafka, bitnami, bitnami-kafka

I want to run kafka on kubernetes using the fallowing commands executed in Jenkins job:

```
helm install kafka bitnami/kafka --set zookeeper.enabled=false --set persistence.enabled=false \
                              --set zookeeper.persistence.enabled=false \
                              --set controller.replicaCount=0 \
                              --set replicaCount=1 \
                              --set kraft.enabled=false \
                              --set externalZookeeper.servers=zookeeper.default.svc.cluster.local
```

I get always during startup:

```
kafka: Zookeeper mode - No Kafka brokers configured
    Zookeper mode has been enabled, but no Kafka brokers nodes have been configured
```

Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Explain why you need Zookeeper mode?

Answer (score 0):

adding broker.replicaCount: 1 should fix this